How to create custom style ads with google and Flutter
I'm currently working on integrating ads into my Flutter app, and I need to create an ad that looks similar to the one shown below:

I’ve already attempted to use the standard AdMob banner ad, but I’m encountering a few challenges. Specifically, the banner ad doesn’t seem to render as intended—it’s not fitting well within my design. Additionally, I’m finding it difficult to customize the size and appearance of the ad to make it match the look and feel of my app.
Here’s an example of what I’ve tried so far with a banner ad:

As you can see, the ad doesn’t look like the desired result. The inability to modify its dimensions or apply custom styles (such as padding, margin, or background color) is particularly frustrating. I want the ad to be more integrated and native to the app’s interface, rather than just a standard ad block.
What Is the best approach for this issue?

To create custom-styled ads with Google AdMob in Flutter:

Add the google_mobile_ads package.
Initialize the Google Mobile Ads SDK in your app.
Load a NativeAd and display it using a custom layout.
Implement a platform-specific AdFactory to define your ad's design.
Test using test ad units, then replace them with real ad unit IDs for production.

